# Indentation of bullets only for first line

Tags: indentation, itemize

I see some questions regarding the indentation of lines in bullets via `itemize`. However, still I am seeking for a working method for my problem. The default layout is

```
xxxxxxxxxx:
    * xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    * xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to have

```
xxxxxxxxxx:
    * xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    * xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In other words, I want the indentation only for the first line of the `item`. If I use something like `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3mm,itemsep=0mm,parsep=0mm,topsep=0mm]`, the result is lie this:

```
xxxxxxxxxx:
* xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
* xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see the whole item is shifted to the left. I don't want that.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: it would be easier if you provided a test document, but you want leftmargin=0pt then specify a labelwidth to force the first line indent (or accept the posted answer, which is easier than I suggested:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `wide` option of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[wide]
  \item Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]